# HTTPS Redirect URL with proxy reverse

Tags: apache, redirect, ssl, reverse-proxy

I've a apache proxy reverse in front of a tomcat webapps with this vhost configuration

I need to redirect the http or https base url to a https stattics url like this :

Redirect `http:/ /xxx.domaine.tld` TO `https:/ /xxx.domaine.tld/JOrgInet/JORGServlet?FNAME=jorgentry.htt&P=LOCATION~FRA;DHTML~1;APPLI~ORGCHART;`

and

Redirect `https:/ /xxx.domaine.tld` TO `https:/ /xxx.domaine.tld/JOrgInet/JORGServlet?
FNAME=jorgentry.htt&P=LOCATION~FRA;DHTML~1;APPLI~ORGCHART;`

Here is the vhost configuration file

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName org.domaine.tld
    Redirect / https://org.domaine.tld/JOrgInet/JORGServlet?FNAME=jorgentry.htt&P=LOCATION~FRA;DHTML~1;APPLI~ORGCHART;
</Virtualhost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

   ServerName org.domaine.tld:443
   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domaine.tld.error.log
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domaine.tld.log combined

   LogLevel warn

   SSLProxyEngine on
   SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/certs/gs_root.pem
   SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/certs/intermediate.pem
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certs/gscert.pem
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certs/gscert.key

   <Location />
        AuthType Basic
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthName "Login LDAP SERVER"
        AuthLDAPURL "ldap://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:389/o=XXXXXXXXXXX?uid"
        Require valid-user
        AuthLDAPRemoteUserAttribute uid
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.+)
        RewriteRule .* - [E=RU:%1]       
        RequestHeader set REMOTE_USER %{RU}e
   </Location>

   <IfModule mod_cache.c>
      <IfModule mod_disk_cache.c>
         CacheDefaultExpire 3600
         CacheEnable disk /
         CacheRoot "/var/cache/apache2"
         CacheDirLevels 2
         CacheDirLength 1
         CacheMaxFileSize 1000000
         CacheMinFileSize 1
         CacheIgnoreCacheControl On
         CacheIgnoreNoLastMod On
         CacheIgnoreQueryString Off
         CacheIgnoreHeaders None
         CacheLastModifiedFactor 0.1
         CacheDefaultExpire 3600
         CacheMaxExpire 86400
         CacheStoreNoStore On
         CacheStorePrivate On
      </IfModule>
   </IfModule>

   ProxyPass / ajp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8009/
   ProxyPassReverse / https://org.domaine.tld/

</VirtualHost>
```

when i acces to the base URL in http it's ok but how to redirect to the complex URL when I access with whith the https base URL...

### Thanks in advance.

EB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mod_rewrite` to do what you want.  In your SSL VirtuaLHost configuration, try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/JOrgInet/JORGServlet?FNAME=jorgentry.htt&P=LOCATION~FRA;DHTML~1;APPLI~ORGCHART; [R]
```

This matches requests for `/` only, and redirects them as requested via a client redirect.

For more information, take a look at the Apache [URL rewriting guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/rewrite/).

Comment: It's Works Perfectly....
I will have try "RedirectMatch" before without success...